# Add text next to slider navigation dots with css

Tags: css

I would like to add text above a slideshow navigation dot. Each dot will have different text. The text should only show when one hovers over the dot. I'm thinking of using CSS before but it`s not working. The text is not displaying.

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dot-0 active">
</ul>
```

```css
.dot-0 {
  position: absolute;
}

.dot-0 ul li.active:before {
  content: 'Good Morning';
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: `.dot-0` ***is*** the `li.active` element, so your selector is incorrect. Try using this instead: `li.active.dot-0:before` - assuming you even really need that many class qualifiers.

Comment: Thank you, but it`s still not working. As per my explanation, I`m seeking to have a text timeline above the navigation dots. Basically each dot will bave a corresponding text that displays once the dot is clicked (active)

Comment: In that case I'm afraid there's not enough detail in the question for it to be answerrable. We need to see a full working example of the code which creates the slideshow in an executable snippet within the question. Please edit to include that detail.